# XSLT - how to change the value of any attribute whose value contains a given substring

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Given the following xml:

```
<inventory>
  <item name="..." sku="123"/>
  <item name="..." sku="not available"/>
  <catalog vendor="...">
      <product id="--not available--"/>
      <product id="345"/>
  </catalog
</inventory>
```

I would like to replace any attribute value (anywhere) that has "not available" in it with `'000'`.

I've tried different combinations in XSLT (it is not my forte), and I'm able to replace them when I put the specific XPath expression for each attribute. Unfortunately, the XML documents I might be dealing with (well formed mind you) might have different structure and attribute naming conventions.

All that matter at is to scan specific attribute values (or value patterns) and replace them with a problem-specific default. I'm finding myself to the point of just hack a solution in Python (load doc, iterate the DOM and modify any attribute in any node that matches the criteria.)

But I would really like to learn the solution for this in XSLT (whether it is replacing attribute values that match a pattern, or just straight string comparisons), if one exists. Professional curiosity if you will.

Any help would be appreciated. Any recommendation on a source or book that explains these XLST/XPath  intricacies would be great as well (I've only found very simple examples, nothing as arbitrary as this.)

Comment: XSLT 1 or 2? In 2 it's easy, in 1 it's impossible, so this is important. :)

Comment: Please post a valid XML input example.

Comment: @biziclop Anything is possible in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, in theory you can write a regexp engine in XSLT 1.0. In practice though, XSLT1 (without third party extensions) has no regular expression support.

Comment: @biziclop regex is not required for this (as Martin Honnen has already shown while I was writing this).

Comment: @michael.hor257k But the original question was (and still is): "XSLT - how to change the value of any attribute whose value matches a regular expression" Of course you can hack your way around any specific case with the rather weak string processing facilities of XSLT1.

Comment: @biziclop No, that was the *title* of the question. The *real question* was "*I would like to replace any attribute value (anywhere) that has "not available" in it with '000'.*" OP mistakenly thought this must be solved in a certain way; there's no reason why you and I should repeat this mistake.

Comment: The title needs to be changed then.

Comment: Thank you everyone, Martin Honnen provided me with a solution, which I tested in various scenarios and works. He also provided an explanation of how it works. Useful and productive. Thanks.

Comment: @luis.espinal "XSLT - how to change the value of any attribute based on their current value"? Or something like this.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Whoever edited and improved the title of my question, many thanks. It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="@*[contains(., 'not available')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">000</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

plus

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The second template is the identity transformation template that used alone copies everything level by level, node by node, always processing any attribute and any child nodes with matching templates. To that we add a template for attributes of any name (`@*`) where the content contains the `not available` string, we create an attribute of the same name and namespace but a different value `000`. With the apply-templates in the identity transformation we have ensured that all attributes are processed and based on the match pattern and template priority any more specific templates perform a transformation, like changing the attribute value. We could add more templates as needed, for instance `<xsl:template match="foo"/>` to remove `foo` elements or `<xsl:template match="bar"><foobar><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></foobar></xsl:template>` to transform `bar` elements to `foobar` elements.

Comment: Thank you sir, that did the trick. I was wondering if you could explain a bit how that works. I thought my match had to be `"node() | @*"`. Order does not matter, or is this the correct way to match any attribute on any node? Thanks.

Comment: @luis.espinal, I haved added a paragraph to explain it.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this helps a lot. Much appreciated.